# sequential date grouping issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, join

I have following query:

```
SELECT sauda_date,
       ExpiryDate,
       Scrip_Code,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyRate, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyAmount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellRate,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END)>
                  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) 
             THEN 'BF' ELSE 'BT' END ) as TradeType, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellAmount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END)
        - SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) as NETQTY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)
        - SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)as NetAmt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)
        - SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) as PNLAmt 
FROM tradeFile 
where Inst_Type='FUTIDX' OR 
      Inst_Type='FUTSTK' and 
      Sauda_Date between 
                 convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "') and 
                 convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "')
group by Scrip_Code,ExpiryDate,sauda_date 
order by Scrip_Code,ExpiryDate,sauda_date
```

This query is giving me following result:

[image]

In this query i am using group by saudadate. Also order by saudadate.

Its showing me 28 Feb 2013 at last and listing further from 1 Mar 2013,2 Mar 2013.....22 Mar 2013.

I wanted to have records to be grouped sequential.
i.e. 28 Feb 2013 first then 1 Mar 2013 , 2 Mar 2013 , 3 Mar 2013...

What changes should i make in above query ?

removing order by makes no difference in the result for above query.

As well convert`(varchar(11),sauda_date)`  also making no difference.

sauda_date is nvarchar

**My Intended result:**

```
Sauda_Date Expiry_Date  ScripCode

28 Feb 2013   .....       ADANIENT  
1 MAR  203    ......      ADANIENT  
1 Mar 2013    .......     ADANIENT
28 FEB 2013   .......     TCS
2 MAR 2013    ....        TCS
```

Comment: what is the data type of `sauda_date`?

Comment: @Freelancer . . . you should format your query so the question is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order by `sauda_date` within `scrip_code` (which is what you appear to want), change the `order by` clause to read:

```
order by Scrip_code, sauda_date, ExpiryDate
```

(If you look at the screenshot in the question, you can see that the results are being sorted on `ExpiryDate` before `sauda_date` - as specified in the query - which is why the rows are being ordered as they are.)

Answer (score 1):

The order by is:

```
order by Scrip_Code,ExpiryDate,sauda_date
```

If you want to order by `sauda_date`, it should go first:

```
order by sauda_date, Scrip_code, ExpiryDate
```

If this is stored as a string (bad choice, but if you do, you should store as "YYYY-MM-DD" format), then try:

```
order by convert(datetime, sauda_date), Scrip_code, ExpiryDate
```

Comment: This is ordering my result by sauda_date but voilating scrip code. i.e. it is showing all the data for 28Feb 2013 for all scrip codes then with 1 Mar 2013 and so on...but my intended result was to show it with one scripcode and its saudadate wise record then another scrip code...etc.

Comment: Then do it using the `ORDER BY` clause. Guess in which order you have to apply the elements?

Comment: @alzaimar got solution through Mark Bannister.